# alerts in sharepoint online fires too many emails

Tags: sharepoint-online

i have created a document library with some folders and files. I added an alert for some users, then when i upload 2 documents in the sharepoint library it sent around 72 emails instead of the details of the 2 document that i just uploaded. Is this supposed to happen like this ?. Is there any way that we can customize it ?

[image]

Comment: on what event you have triggered email? 
Change the 'Change Type' property  from library alert setting and select 'New items are added'.

Comment: i have added it on all changes

Comment: but still there shouldnt be 72 emails right

Comment: that depends, if you are doing some operation on the list/library items using workflow. like update/delete items. If NOT then it should not fire that many emails.
Does Change type property works in you case?

Comment: i have updated the question with the alert configuration page. there are no workflows associated with this document library.